# hiera CLI lookup fails but puppet agent -t works

Tags: puppet

[root@puppet puppet]# cat /etc/hiera.yaml

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: '/etc/puppet/hieradata'
:hierarchy:
  - env/%{::environment}/fqdn/%{::fqdn}
  - hostgroup/%{::hostgroup1}
  - global
```

[root@puppet puppet]# cat hieradata/env/dev/fqdn/client00.itw.local.yaml

```
fruit::a:
  - 'DevFQDN-kiwi'
```

[root@puppet puppet]# cat environments/dev/modules/fruit/manifests/init.pp

```
class fruit(
        $a = hiera('fruit::a' ),
        $b = hiera('fruit::b'),
        $c = hiera('fruit::c')
) {
        notify { 'foo':
                message => "a is: ${a}, b is: ${b}, c is : ${c}",
        }
}
```

fruit::a seems to resolve fine on client00.itw.local

```
[root@client00 ~]# puppet agent -t
Warning: Local environment: "production" doesn't match server specified node  environment "dev", switching agent to "dev".
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for client00.itw.local
Info: Applying configuration version '1411407772'
Notice: a is: DevFQDN-kiwi, b is: HostgroupAll-orange, c is : global-lime-C
```

But CLI hiera does not return the correct value on the puppet master

```
[root@puppet puppet]# hiera -d fruit::a ::fqdn=client00.itw.local ::hostgroup1=all
DEBUG: Mon Sep 22 13:57:16 -0400 2014: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: Mon Sep 22 13:57:16 -0400 2014: Looking up fruit::a in YAML backend
DEBUG: Mon Sep 22 13:57:16 -0400 2014: Looking for data source hostgroup/all
DEBUG: Mon Sep 22 13:57:16 -0400 2014: Looking for data source global
DEBUG: Mon Sep 22 13:57:16 -0400 2014: Found fruit::a in global
["global-lime-A"]
```

With mcollective, hiera -d fruit::a -m client00.itw.local, I got the same result.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure your hiera.yaml is under /etc? Because usually puppet agent use /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml while cli use /etc/hiera.yaml https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/configuring.html

Comment: Yes. I sym-linked two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

environment is a Puppet specific fact, included in Puppet libraries

When using hiera in the command line [you have to pass those facts](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/command_line.html#fact-sources).

Comment: Thanks."hiera -d fruit::a ::environment=dev ::fqdn=client00.itw.local"  returned the correct value.

Comment: Follow up question: "hiera -d fruit::a -m client00.itw.local ::enviornment=dev" returns the wrong value. "hiera -d fruit::a -m client00.itw.local ::enviornment=dev ::fqdn=client00.itw.local" returns the correct value. But I was hoping mcollective would save me some typing.